# Is there a way to escape all args send to a function automatically?

Tags: php, mysqli

Is there a way that I can put a code at the begging of any function so all passed arguments/variables are looped to

```
$var = mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS['mysqli'],$var);
```

I use this to make it easier but it seems stupid

```
function esc($var)
{
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS['mysqli'],$var);
}

 function loginattempt($email,$plainpassword,$keepalive=0)
{
    $email=esc($email);
    $plainpassword=esc($plainpassword);
    $keepalive=esc($keepalive);
}
```

I am totally against prepared statements (I lost 3 days trying to make stuff work with prepared statements then decided i will stick to procedural mysqli)

Comment: `compact`,`array_map`, `extract`, but prepared statements are nicer :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## NO NO NO and once more NO

This would be useless and wrong, due to wrong assumption - you don't understand what escaping is and what it is used for.

You should use **prepared statements** instead of this function.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong ...
From what I understand escaping is used to avoid mysql injection ...
or give me an advise because I ended up writing 20 lines for the object oriented mysqli instead or usually 3-4 lines...

Comment: It'll be kind if you explained what you mean please

Comment: Didn't I already? What you have read on avoiding mysql injection is a plain rubbish. Escaping has nothing to do with injections. You have to use prepared statements. For the convenient code you have to use PDO, not mysqli

Comment: Just saw this old question, few months later I started using prepared statement, Thank you. I've been working with prepared statements last three years